# Hyperledger fabric not build on my virtual machine

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I try to build hyperledger fabric project. But it built with next errors:

[image: Errors after trying to build hyperledger project]

I set gopath:

[image: gopath]

And uses linux mint 17.3 Rosa OS 64bit on virtual machine (virtual box).

What is the problem, how can work around those errors ?

Comment: why are you building as root? Have you followed the directions at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/dev-setup/devenv.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Fabric is cloned into goPath or goRoot. Since you are making as root, ensure root has the correct go env. 'make all' seems to take a while. 45 minutes?